# Sorting list with rules with python

Tags: python, sorting, arraylist

I have a list like this

```
['File3', 'File007', 'File3a', 'File10', 'File11', 'File1', 'File4', 'File5', 'File9', 'File8', 'File8b1', 'File8b2', 'File8b11', 'File6']
```

When I sort it with `sorted()` in python. it will become like this:

```
['File007', 'File1', 'File10', 'File11', 'File3', 'File3a', 'File4', 'File5', 'File6', 'File8', 'File8b1', 'File8b11', 'File8b2', 'File9']
```

But what I want is:

```
['File1', 'File3', 'File3a', 'File4', 'File5', 'File6', 'File007', 'File8', 'File8b1', 'File8b2', 'File8b11', 'File9', 'File10', 'File11']
```

The number sort it must be:
File1, File2, File3, File10

not like:
File1, File10, File2, File3

if it has 0 digit like this File007, it will count as 7

if it has alphabet after number, like File3a, it will sort like this:
File3, File3a, File3b, ...

is there a ways to add this rules in sorting the list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a function that is run during the sorting process

```
# Sort a list based on removing leading zeros
def mysort(x): 
    return int(str(x).replace("0",""))

L = ["002", "013", "001", "005"] 

print ("Normal sorting :", sorted(L)) 
print ("Sorted with key:", sorted(L, key = mysort))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to define you own sorting rules, by passing the `key` keyword argument to the `sorted` function. Some code that seems to do exactly what you want could look like this:

```
import re

def key_fn(f):
    # the f[4:] part just gets the part of each string after 'File'
    groups = re.match(r'(\d*)(\D*)(\d*)', f[4:]).groups()
    def try_parse_int(x):
        # x should be either an empty string or something we can
        # parse into an int
        try:
            return int(x)
        except ValueError:
            return None
    return try_parse_int(groups[0]), groups[1], try_parse_int(groups[2])

files = ['File3','File007','File3a','File10','File11','File1','File4','File5',
    'File9','File8','File8b1','File8b2','File8b11','File6']

sorted_files = sorted(files, key=key_fn)
```

This supports any amount of digits, followed (optionally) by any amount non-digits, followed (optionally) by any amount of digits again.

Comment: You might want to convert to integers groups that are formed by digits.